# Chrome Extension Add Script Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

In a Chrome extension the following code

```
**background.js**
var elt = document.createElement("script");
elt.type="text/javascript";
elt.innerHTML = "alert('hello world');";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(elt);
```

Throws this error

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'".
```

This is despite I have this line in manifest.js

```
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

Any thoughts why this error is thrown ?

Comment: Typo? 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self' bad semicolon?

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism for relaxing the restriction against executing inline JavaScript. In particular, setting a script policy that includes **`unsafe-inline`** will have no effect.

It is working with following state:

#### manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Page Action Demo",
    "description": "This demonstrates Page Action",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://www.google.co.in/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "myscript.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "https://www.google.co.in/*"
    ]
}
```

#### myscript.js

```
var elt = document.createElement("script");
elt.type="text/javascript";
elt.innerHTML = "alert('hello world');";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(elt);
```

Can you share relevant code, if this does not help?

Comment: OK my mistake I didn't explain the code I am running is in background.js , I think that's why yours is working (content script) and mine isn't , no ?

Comment: @Joel_Blum:If the code is in background.js you can not inject script at all, so it is only possible in the way i do .. and you are correct